# Send an ajax call to a function in YII

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am in need to send an ajax call to a function in following directory structure

```js
Yii::$app->request->absoluteUrl."protected/humhub/modules/post/controllers/PostController/UploadMusicFile";
```

my view function

```js
  function uploadImage(){
      var url = '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."protected/humhub/modules/post/controllers/PostController/UploadMusicFile"; ?>';
      console.log(url);
      return false;
        $.ajax({
          url:'<?php echo Yii::$app->createUrl("Post/UploadMusicFile"); ?>',
          method:'post',
          data:{file:$('input[type="file"]')},
          dataType:'',
          contentType:false,
          processData:false,
          success:function(data){
            var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
          },
          error:function(data){
            console.log("Error "+data);
          }
        });

    }
```

function which i am posting to

```js
  public function UploadMusicFile(){
      $file = Yii::$app->request->post('file');
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($file);
      echo "</pre>";
      exit();
      $target_dir = "/home/jmwglobaladmin/public_html/melmory/uploads/music_memory/";
      $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["files"]["name"][0]);
      foreach ($_FILES["files"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
          if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
              $tmp_name = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
              move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file);
              $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
              $command = $connection->createCommand('select id from post order by id desc limit 1');
              $result = $command->queryAll();
              $new_id = $result[0]['id']+1;
              $file_name = "abc.mp3";
              $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
              $command_insert = $connection->createCommand('insert into memory_music (post_id,memory_music) values ("'.$new_id.'","'.$file_name.'")');
              $result = $command_insert->execute();
          }
      }
    }
```

I get the error of 404. How to pass proper url in yii to a function which is present in directory structure like mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Basics. Your function is not an action.

Change this:

```
public function UploadMusicFile()
```

To this:

```
public function actionUploadMusicFile()
```